# Разница в индексах базы данных SQLite и ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Читаю книгу HeadFirst Android и там упущен этот момент. При выполнении кода из листинга у меня выводится на один элемент меньше. Т.е. можно сделать вывод что у БД _id нумеруется с 1, а у ListView с 0. Так ли это? И если да, то есть ли какой-то способ чтобы избежать этого или исправить помимо добавления единицы к индексу. В коде ниже я уже добавил +1. (Вкратце о приложении, есть ListView и при клике по нему происходит переход к Detail View, и уже там запрос к бд.)
Код активности списка:

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Cursor cursor;
private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);

    ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);

    SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        mSQLiteDatabase = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query("DRINK",
                new String[] {"_id","NAME"},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        listDrinks.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Drink> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Drink.drinks
    );


    listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener);
}
```

Код Detail Activity:

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_DRINKID = "drink_id";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

    int drinkId = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKID) + 1;
```

Comment: Начальный индекс у массива и у коллекций равна 0. Т.е. первый элемент имеет индекс 0

Comment: Сама соль в том, что при взаимодействии ListAdapter и SQLite происходит сдвиг, а вот при взаимодействии с SimpleCursorAdapter все в порядке! То есть если использовать оба возникают существенные проблемы

Comment: Забудьте про цифры, которые хранит `_id` - это в простейшем примере у вас они отличаются на единицу от индексов списка. А дальше будет веселее - удалили запись из базы - id пропущен, добавили сортировку в выборку - вообще всё перемешалось. Поэтому никогда не пытайтесь использовать позицию в качестве id базы и наоборот.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо огромное, все сразу прояснилось, но тем не менее интересует Best Practice в данном случае. То есть следует по id ListView найти название элемента списка и уже по нему вытащить из БД данные в DetailActivity (DrinkActivity)

Comment: Название или другое содержимое таблицы  может быть не уникальным - поэтому надёжнее и эффективнее использовать всё же первичный ключ (`_id` в нашем случае). Если используются CursorAdapter-ы, то id приходит последним параметром в `onItemClick()`, или можно попросить по позиции `adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(position)`. Другие адаптеры не знают откуда брать id и выдают вместо него позицию - поэтому вы должны сами об этом позаботиться. Например добавить соответствующее поле в модель данных и брать оттуда по позиции типа: `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).id`

Comment: @woesss Спасибо!

Comment: А еще разобраться со всем этим(SQLiteDatabase,Coursor и тд) это круто, и появляется понимание как все это работает. Но в реальной практике все это не используется, так как много кода, сложно читать и тд. Почитайте про Room это очень мощная обертка над SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы опираетесь на ID элементов списка, в то время как Вам нужно опираться на ID элементов базы данных.

Если у Вас будет статичный список, тогда Вы кое-как сможете подогнать ID элементов списка с ID из базы данных. Но, что, если Вы сделаете функцию удаления элементов из базы данных? Тогда в итоге, можете прийти к такому, что первый элемент из списка будет иметь ID равный 45 [по базе данных].

Поэтому, лучше всего завести отдельный массив для хранения ID элементов из базы данных:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> itemsID;
```

Затем, в моменте, где Вы с помощью cursor получаете данные из базы данных, брать ID элементов из базы данных и добавлять в наш массив:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    //получаем ID элементов из базы данных
    int currentID = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
    
    //добавляем их в наш массив
    itemsID.add(currentID);
}
```

И уже в методе обработки выбора элементов из списка, использовать наш массив, чтобы получить заведомый ID элемента:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    //получаем ID выбранного элемента из списка
    int currentID = itemsID.get(position);
    
    //переходим на экран DrinkActivity, передав ID выбранного элемента
    Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, currentID);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Вкратце:
У Вас есть элементы, как я понял: данные по напиткам.
Вы создали базу данных и занесли туда данные по напиткам. У каждого напитка свой ID [по базе данных].

Теперь, Вы хотите взять данные из базы данных, добавить их в список и вывести на экран.
У каждого напитка по два ID: по базе данных и по самому списку.

Чтобы дальше работать с данными по напиткам - нужно знать их ID по базе данных, а не по ID из списка. Значит, нам нужно хранить ID напитков по базе данных, чтобы заранее знать: какой ID напитка находится на каждой позиции списка.

Краткий пример.
Было 7 напитков. Мы удалили первые 4. Осталось 3. После вывода на экран в виде списка, каждый будет иметь по два ID:

Напиток 1: ID по базе данных = 5, по списку = 0

Напиток 2: ID по базе данных = 6, по списку = 1

Напиток 3: ID по базе данных = 7, по списку = 2

Мы добавляем ID напитков по базе данных в отдельный массив:

```
itemsID = {5, 6, 7};
```

И когда мы захотим выбрать напиток из списка, нам достаточно знать на какой позиции находится выбранный напиток, чтобы взять его ID из нашего массива itemsID.

Скажем, мы выбрали второй напиток, он находится на позиции 1 по списку. А это соответствует ID = 6 [по базе данных]:

```
int itemID = itemsID.get(1);
```

Так как добавление элементов в список происходит после запроса к базе данных, то, мы можем без каких-либо проблем реализовать сортировку, поиск, фильтрацию и прочие функции, ибо наш отдельный массив itemsID для хранения ID по базе данных - будет обновляться по мере изменения списка.

Сортировка.

В самой базе данных есть функция сортировка. Выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT*FROM drinks ORDER BY price DESC
```

где DESC - в порядке убывания, а ASC - в порядке возрастания.

В самом коде это можно применить с помощью Cursor, в моменте, где мы обращаемся к базе данных, чтобы получить наши данные. Например, отсортируем напитки по убыванию цены:

```
 cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(
                      "DRINK",
                      new String[] {"_id","NAME"},
                      null, 
                      null, 
                      null, 
                      null, 
                      Drinks.COLUMN_PRICE + "DESC"
    );
```

И лишь после сортировки самой базой данных, мы заполним наш список, где каждый элемент списка будет иметь соответствующий ID по базе данных в массиве itemsID.

Фильтрация.

Фильтрация, а если быть точнее - выборка определенных данных из базы данных тоже реализована следующим образом. Скажем, нам нужно вывести напитки, цена которых равна 5$.
В самой базе данных запрос будет следующим:

```
SELECT*FROM drinks WHERE price=5;
```

В самом коде будем использовать тот же самый Cursor.
Сначала укажем столбец, который в нашем условии выборки:

```
String selection = Drinks.COLUMN_PRICE + "=?";
```

А затем, укажем значение выборки:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {"5"};
```

И наконец, укажем в самом Cursor наши условия:

```
cursor = mSQLiteDatabase.query(
                          "DRINK",
                          new String[] {"_id","NAME"},
                          selection, 
                          selectionArgs, 
                          null, 
                          null, 
                          null
        );
```

В итоге, в наш список попадут те данные, которые мы заранее отфильтровали.
И наш массив itemsID - изначально будет соответствовать верным ID по базе данных.

Поиск.

Если Вам нужно найти сам элемент из базы данных, то, можете сначала провести сортировку [показана выше], а затем, пробежаться по нашему массиву itemsID, используя двоичный поиск.

То есть, сначала отсортировали данные, а затем берете массив itemsID и проверяете каждый ID на совпадение.

Другое дело, если Вы хотите произвести стандартный поиск: по названию напитка, по его компонентам и так далее. В этом случае, при получении данных из базы данных, просто берете и проверяете каждое полученное значение с помощью алгоритма поиска подстроки в строке [алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта].

Можно произвести и другие функции. Самое главное - у нас есть массив, в котором каждый напиток из списка - имеет верный ID по базе данных.

Вам все равно придется где-нибудь хранить ID напитков по базе данных, чтобы не спутать их с ID по списку. Это самое просто решение. Сам когда-то столкнулся с этой проблемой, после прочтения той же книги Head First. Проще решения, чем просто хранить ID в отдельном массиве - не нашел. Если сможете найдете - еще лучше.

Comment: Ответ хороший, подробный, но решение не очень. Что если мы реализуем сортировку, фильтрацию, поиск по списку? Тогда нужно будет и со списком айдишников проделывать тоже самое - это несколько неудобно и можно забыть/напутать. Если мы конвертируем данные из курсора в список дата-классов, то и айдишники можем записать туда же, тогда проблем нет - берём по позиции дата-класс и из него `id`. Если не конвертируем, а используем курсор напрямую, то и id можем взять из курсора - незачем их выносить в дополнительный список.

Comment: Я обновил свой комментарий выше, где дополнил про сортировку, фильтрацию и прочие функции.

Суть в том, что мы каждый раз обновляем наш массив с ID. Если используем сортировку, то не нужно сортировать сам массив, нужно отсортировать сами данные из базы данных, а массив с ID будет заполняться уже после сортировки, после получения данных.

Comment: Не ожидал такого подробного ответа. Спасибо, по полочкам разложили

Comment: Никаких проблем! :~]